# Script opens infinite instances of Internet Explorer, without setting active window

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys, active-window

I wrote a vbscript program to automatically join Google Meet sessions, with the code that is required to enter the meet generated based on the date and time. Whenever I run the program, it opens in the background of the computer in infinite windows(repeatedly opening a new instance of Google Meet every second). The keystrokes that are supposed to be directed toward Internet Explorer are instead sent to whatever is active. The line of code that is supposed to make it the active window are not working: `WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"` I believe that this below section is what is causing problems. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
option explicit
dim webbrowser, WshShell

set webbrowser = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
set WshShell = createobject("Wscript.Shell")


webbrowser.statusbar = false
webbrowser.menubar = false
webbrowser.toolbar = false
webbrowser.visible = true

webbrowser.navigate("https://meet.google.com/")

wscript.sleep(3000)

WshShell.AppActivate Internet Explorer
WshShell.sendkeys "{enter}"
```

Comment: Move it up. A program has 2 seconds to play with windows. You sleep for 3 seconds. See the proper way to wait for a page using `readystate = 4` https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=readystate%20%5bvbscript%5d

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why did you use `sendkeys` ?

You should write something like that :

```
Option explicit
dim webbrowser
set webbrowser = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
webbrowser.statusbar = false
webbrowser.menubar = false
webbrowser.toolbar = false
webbrowser.visible = true
webbrowser.navigate("https://meet.google.com/")

Do while webbrowser.readystate <> 4 
    wscript.sleep 200 
Loop
```